# Mesh distorted during animations exporting from Blender + Rigify to Unity 2020

Tags: unity, animation, blender, fbx, rigging

I finished my first 3D Character with a couple of animations using **Blender 2.8** and **Rigify**.

I'm exporting it to Blender as FBX file and everything seems to work. The only problem I have is with the **Walk** animation. There are points where the mesh of my character just starts to deform when I play the animation in Unity.

Here you can see the differences between Blender and Unity:

[image: Unity deformations]
[image: Blender Perfect Animation]

Export Settings:

[image: Export settings]

What am I doing wrong? In Blender, everything works properly and there are no deformations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111554/discussion-between-pikalek-and-ravenjegames).

Comment: I too want to know the answer - I think it has to do with exporting the Rigify rig and the WGT-bones which confuses Unity. Maybe baking animations to the metarig armiture is the trick By the way: Weirdly, I'm modelling and animating a squirrel for Unity at the moment